# Extracting text and ignoring "b" tag

Tags: web, web-scraping, scrapy, tags

Trying to extract the following text using:

'''
response.css("span[class = 'summary content']::text").extract()
'''

```
<span class="summary content">With its multiple cleaning modes, the <b>LG Hom-Bot Square</b> gives the user a terrific amount of control over how it operates. Its remote is convenient, easy to use, and well-designed.</span>
```

But gives me

Out[1]:
['With its multiple cleaning modes, the ',
 ' gives the user a terrific amount of control over how it operates. Its remote is convenient, easy to use, and well-designed.']

missing "LG Hom-Bot Square"

How can I just ignore the b tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually take the turn around using a join:

```
summary = response.css("span[class = 'summary content']::text").extract() 
" ".join(summary)
```

In that case, you won´t be avoiding `<b>`, but the result will be the same as you want